# Find closest numbers in array to given value

Tags: ruby, algorithm, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm looking to create a method that will return to me the 5 closest numbers in an array. Here is what I have to get me started. I'm looking to compare differences but I feel there has to be a simpler way .

```
def get_suggested_items
    @suggested_items = []
    new_price = self.price
    products = Product.all
    products.each do |product, difference|
        price = product.price
        old_difference = new_price - product.price
        difference = (new_price - product.price).abs
        while difference < old_difference 
            @suggested_items << product
        end

end
```

I'm looking to have returned the array @suggested_items with the 5 closest products by the price

Comment: What is your sample input and expected output?

Comment: Hey thereI'm looking to have returned the array @suggested_items with the 5 closest products by the price

Comment: Yes, we know that part. We don't know what your data looks like, so supply a minimal example of what would be in your database, and which values would be selected. Don't expect us to imagineer that sort of thing because you never know what you'll get back in return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL was designed for this sort of thing. Add the following class method to your `Product` model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.with_price_nearest_to(price)
    order("abs(products.price - #{price})")
  end
end
```

Then you can write:

```
Product.with_price_nearest_to(3.99).limit(5)
```

There is a distinct performance advantage to this approach over what you outlined in your question. In this case, the database does the calculation and sorting for you and returns to ActiveRecord only the 5 products that you need. When you do `Product.all` or even `Product.each` you're forcing ActiveRecord to instantiate a model for every row in your table, which gets expensive as the table gets larger.

Note that this approach still requires a full table scan; if you want to improve the performance further, you can add an index to `price` column on the `products` table.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thanks so much it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `arr` is a sorted array of integers. (If it's not sorted, then sort as the first step.)
 I assume you want to find a sequence of five elements from the array, `a = arr[i,5]`, such that `a.last-a.first` is minimum for all `i`, `0 <= i <= arr.size-4`. If that's correct, then it's simply:

```
start_index = (arr.size-4).times.min_by { |i| arr[i+4]-arr[i] }
```

Suppose

```
arr = [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 23, 24, 24, 25, 30]
start_index = (arr.size-4).times.min_by { |i| arr[i+4]-arr[i] }
  #=> 4
```

So the "closest" five numbers would be:

```
arr[4,5]
  #=> [8, 9, 11, 12, 13]
```